# SQL Syntax error using WEHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM sorular WEHERE test_id='%s' ORDER BY id LIMIT '%s', '%s'",
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(stripslashes($testid))), 
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(stripslashes($start))), 
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(stripslashes($perpage))));
```

and I am getting error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test_id='1' ORDER BY id LIMIT '4', '2'' at line 1

Comment: WHERE is spelled wrong in what you posted.  Could that be the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limit and offset are always integer. Try this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM sorular WHERE test_id='%s' ORDER BY id LIMIT %s, %s",
mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(stripslashes($testid))), 
$start, 
$perpage);
```

Anyway, you filter variables in worst way. Integers are integres, use `$int = (int) $maybeInteger;`, strings - you do `mysql_real_escape_string()` and `stripslashes()` at the same time, this functions are familiar, look to manual. `htmlentities()` should be used after filtration.

As it was said, the correct answer is: `WEHERE` => `WHERE`.

Comment: `WHERE` is _still_ spelt wrong.

Comment: You might want to fix the `WEHERE`, too.

Comment: mySQL will convert `'1'` to `1` itself. Quotes aren't necessary around numbers but that will not cause an error.

Comment: OK, I hadn't seen this yet. But I've written about security practices.

Answer (score 1):

You just made a simple typo : WEHERE -> WHERE

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled the word WHERE wrong in your query.